# Prove $\int_{0}^{\pi} \sqrt[n]{\prod_{k=1}^{n}\csc^2(x-\alpha_k)}dx\geq4π$ for reals $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...\alpha_n$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, inequality, definite-integrals, integral-inequality

> Prove for all positive integer $n$ and for all $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,...\alpha_n \in \mathbb{R}$ Prove that
> $\int_{0}^{\pi} \sqrt[n]{\prod_{k=1}^{n}\csc^2(x-\alpha_k)}dx\geq4π$

I have tried by applying GM-HM inequality
We know the inequility GM$\geq $ HM

Appliying this on $\csc^2(x-\alpha_1), \csc^2(x-\alpha_2), \cdots \csc^2(x-\alpha_n)$ We will get

$$\sqrt[n]{\prod_{k=1}^{n}\csc^2(x-\alpha_k)}\geq \frac{n}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin^2 (x-\alpha_k)}$$
I am stuck after that. Please help me to proceed further

Comment: A little remark : for different reasons, it is advisable to transform your cosecant(s) into the inverse of sine(s) : it is better to limit the use of trigonometric functions to $\sin, \cos, \tan$ (for example, in my country, France, cosec function is never used).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Once more this robot doesn't understand a very clear question, as is clear the fact that the asker hasn't given evidence of real work (cases $n=1$ or $n=2$ ?....)

Comment: for $n=1$ the integral is divergent and approaching infinity so it is greater than 4π

Comment: The GM-HM relation is too weak here, since for $n=2, \alpha_1=0, \alpha_2=\pi/2$, $\int_0^\pi \frac{2}{\sin^2(x) + \sin^2(x-\pi/2)}\, dx = 2\pi$.

Comment: Any other way that we may proceed

Comment: This is deep, since it is asking for the inequality $$\int_0^{\pi}\exp\left(-\int_0^{2\pi}\log \sin^2(x-\alpha)\mu(d\alpha)\right)dx\geq 4\pi.$$ where $\mu(d\alpha)$ is an arbitrary probability on the circle.